# I used crudrepository findAll() method on MAGICNOTIFY_CARD_INFO table but it shows other columns from another table MAGICNOTIFY_PRICE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I tried to select all columns from the table `MAGICNOTIFY_CARD_INFO`, so i wrote a code;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MagicnotifyApplication.class, args);
    MagicnotifyCardInfoRepository magicnotifyCardInfoRepository =
            context.getBean(MagicnotifyCardInfoRepository.class);
    magicnotifyCardInfoRepository.findAll();
    //SpringApplication.run(MagicnotifyApplication.class, args);
}
```

and this is the entity i wanted to select;

```
public class MagicnotifyCardInfoID implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "koname")
private String koname;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "cardkingdom")
private String cardkingdom;

@Column(name = "cardkingdomfoil")
private String cardkingdomfoil;

@Column(name = "set")
private String set;

@Column(name = "setName")
private String setName;

@Column(name = "reldate")
private Date reldate;

@Column(name = "rarity")
private String rarity;

@Column(name = "uuid")
private String uuid;

@ManyToOne
private MagicnotifyUuidName magicnotifyUuidName;

@ManyToOne
private MagicnotifySetInfo magicnotifySetInfo;
```

}

```
public class MagicnotifyCardInfo implements Serializable {
@EmbeddedId
private MagicnotifyPriceID id;
```

}

```
public interface MagicnotifyCardInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<MagicnotifyCardInfo, Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM MAGICNOTIFY_CARD_INFO", nativeQuery = true)
List<MagicnotifyCardInfo> findByAll();

List<MagicnotifyCardInfo> findAll();
```

}

but after querying, it tries to select other column item from table
MAGICNOTIFY_PRICE;

```
public class MagicnotifyPriceID implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "foil")
private BigDecimal foil;

@Column(name = "normal")
private BigDecimal normal;

@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;

@Column(name = "key")
private String key;

@ManyToOne
private MagicnotifyUuidName id;
```

}

```
public class MagicnotifyPrice implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private MagicnotifyPriceID id;
```

}

I'm not sure why it happens from differently mapped two tables; how can i select from initial table MAGICNOTIFY_CARD_INFO and select from its columns?

Comment: You mapped 2 additional tables what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have not mentioned any primary key using @Id annotation inside either of your **MagicnotifyCardInfoID** class or **MagicnotifyPriceID** class
Secondly, you have given same @EmbeddedId fields "MagicnotifyPriceID id" in both the below classes

```
public class MagicnotifyCardInfo implements Serializable {
@EmbeddedId
private MagicnotifyPriceID id;
}

public class MagicnotifyPrice implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private MagicnotifyPriceID id;
}
```

### **I don't see @Embeddable used anywhere in your program**
Please refer https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable

```
public interface MagicnotifyCardInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<MagicnotifyCardInfo, Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM MAGICNOTIFY_CARD_INFO", nativeQuery = true)
List<MagicnotifyCardInfo> findByAll();

List<MagicnotifyCardInfo> findAll();

}
```

**In the above class you are passing "JpaRepository<MagicnotifyCardInfo, *Long*>"
Long as the data type of a primary key in your entity "MagicnotifyCardInfo"
which does not even exist.**

Please fix these and try again.